# Android: Delete entire database

Tags: android, adb, android-database

I would like to delete a complete database created by my application.

Do you know any adb command, or android sentence to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to start up your emulator with the command: *-wipe-data*

Comment: FYI, `-wipedata` will actually delete the entire user data image - http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

Answer (score 12):

You can run the command:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell (or whatever port you use)
cd /data/data/<packagename>/databases/
```

By typing ls, you will see the databases created and you can remove the one you want with rm

```
rm myapp.db
```

See more [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite)

Answer (score 6):

Also, in Eclipse you can go to "Window -> Show View -> Other... -> Android -> File Explorer"

Then navigate to "data/data//databases"

Select the database file, then click the red minus sign to "delete the selection"

Answer (score 2):

go to DDMS->FleExplorer-data/data/packagename/databases/name_of_database

click on the name_of_database and press the red minus!

If you don't have the FileExplorer go to  Window->ShowView->FileExplorer

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is too obvious but uninstalling the application via Manage Applications will remove the db, assuming it's in the application's files dir.

Answer (score 1):

The clear data button will actually delete the database without uninstalling the entire app.